# Xcode can run my program, but I can't run it manually

Tags: xcode, macos, dynamic-linking

I have a project with a dynamic library and an executable that links against it. I can successfully start it with Xcode, but when I try to run it from the command line, dyld complains about the library not being in the install path:

```
$ /Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT/Build/Products/Debug/EXECUTABLE 
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libMyLib.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT/Build/Products/Debug/EXECUTABLE 
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

The problem is quite clear: the library isn't in its advertised install path. However, I don't really want to deploy it there, and besides, Xcode still manages to start my program.

How can I run my program without installing the library in `/usr/local/lib`?

Comment: Do you really need a dynamic library? A static one might be easier to use, if you have access to the library source code...

Comment: @Macmade, I'm using a dynamic library because it contains core components that are shared between the program and several plug-ins. I guess it could be made a framework instead, but making it static would be asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If you're relying on a dylib, then it needs to be installed in the appropriate location.

Using a framework might help, as you can package it in your application, using `@executable_path`...
But then, of course, you won't be able to share it across different applications.

So basically, you need to tell Xcode to install your dynamic library.
This can be done in your build settings, in the **Deployment** section.

Mainly, **Deployment location**, **Installation directory**, **Skip install**, etc...

Note that you can also do this for frameworks, installing them into `/Library/Frameworks/`

Comment: Any idea how Xcode runs it without the lib in the right location?

Comment: You can look at the way Xcode links your main executable with the library, in the build log view (last icon in the left sidebar)... It basically uses the full path of the library in the temporary build directory instead of the library name, as you would expect for a release build.

Comment: Then why can't I run *this* build, if it's made to look for the libraries in the build directory?